# Azure ML Prediction Is Constant

Tags: azure, machine-learning, data-science, azure-machine-learning-service, machine-learning-model

I am using the Azure ML model available at https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Weather-prediction-model-1 to design a prediction mechanism based on temperature and humidity. I haven't done any changes to the existing model and feeding in data from a simulator. The prediction output is stuck at 0.489944100379944. I have taken over 17k samples and still, the prediction is constant at this value.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

*N.B. - This is my first stint with ML*

Comment: What does the data from the simulator look like that you're predicting on?

Comment: The simulator sends in a JSON string.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the data so we can see what may be going on?

Comment: 1. The sample message from the IoT is as follows 
`{
  "messageId": 222,
  "deviceId": "Raspberry Pi Web Client",
  "temperature": 31.47257074688408,
  "humidity": 66.25091368292911
}`
2. I have uploaded the sample training data at https://github.com/sudeephazra/python-introduction/blob/master/Weather%20Dataset_Sample.csv
3. Also, I have uploaded the sample Excel apps file from Azure ML at https://github.com/sudeephazra/python-introduction/blob/master/Weather%20prediction%20model-SampleData.xlsm
Please let me know if any further details are needed.

Comment: The query that I am using in my Stream Analytics job is 
`WITH azureml AS (
    select EventEnqueuedUtcTime,temperature, humidity, 
    azureml(temperature, humidity) as 
    result from raspberrypi3
) 
select System.TimeStamp time, cast(result.temperature as float) as temperature,
cast(result.humidity as float) as humidity,
cast(result.[Scored Probabilities] as float) as chance,
result.[Scored Labels]  scored_label
INTO
    MyIoT
FROM
    azureml`
The output captures the value of result.temperature and result.humidity properly but the prediction is messed up. :(

Comment: I am using column selectors to select only the temperature and humidity for the prediction.
The function signature is 
`azureml ( temperature NVARCHAR(MAX) , humidity NVARCHAR(MAX) ) RETURNS RECORD
`

Comment: Can you try [this model](https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/Experiment/Weather-prediction-model-example) and see if it gives you better results?

Comment: Nope. Still the same. :( 
I think my function call is doing something wrong. But I am unable to pin the blame on the function because it is sending me back the temperature and humidity, only the prediction is stuck at one point. But when I am testing the ML model from ML Studio; the prediction does change as expected; depending on the inputs.

Comment: Dang :(. Maybe it's something to do with the input data itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170025/discussion-between-sudeep-hazra-and-jon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by the training dataset. The dataset had characters in the humidity and temperature columns. This led to the model expecting characters but operating on floating point numbers. I cleaned the dataset and ensured that there are only floats in the temperature and humidity columns. Then I used this training data for the model and phew!!!! Everything's working now.